# Is there anyway to use glob to import in vercel?

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

Trying to use mikro-orm and type-graphql in nextjs.

On simple nextjs, this works

```
const resolverPaths = await glob( `${process.cwd()}/src/pages/api/graphql/**/*.resolver.ts` );
    const resolvers = await Promise.all( resolverPaths.map( ( resolverPath ) => import( `.${resolverPath.split( 'graphql' )[ 1 ]}` ) ) );
```

but it will not work on vercel. There are around 20-30 resolvers and I don't want to include them 1 by 1.

Any other way to do it?

Comment: _"it will not work on vercel"_ - Do you get any error? What error are you seeing?

Comment: Building with nextjs runs in a separate build folder, trying to use glob doesn't return any files. And I couldn't get process.cwd() or absolute paths to work